# Fantasy book involving a post modern civilization and a young man on a quest with two large greyhound-type dogs

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

People live in barricaded villages because wild dogs are a problem. The government 'taxes' men to dig in ruins, trying to find a particular giant computer.

After this young man starts his quest, two large greyhound-type dogs join him. He names them Followree & Followro, male & female. At some point they stand up on their hind legs and prophecy. He tells a myth 'explaining' the civil collapse: "That little man Atom was broken in two, his head separated from his body", and there were consequences from that. He came across a black  Mandelbrot Buddha-type figure that he understood was a powerful Female force or symbol.

I do not remember the ending, but I was interested in the author who did not write a lot but had another book with (?) Gurdjieff-type cosmic levels of consciousness  (I think). It was probably published in the 1980s or  earlier.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/270830/book-set-in-the-far-future-about-a-tribal-community-boy-who-is-magical

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you're thinking of ***[Riddley Walker](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/776573.Riddley_Walker)*** (1980) by Russell Hoban.

From Goodreads:

> In the far distant future, the country laid waste by nuclear holocaust, twelve-year-old Riddley Walker tells his story in a language as fractured as the world in which he lives. As Riddley steps outside the confines of his small world, he finds himself caught up in intrigue and a frantic quest for power, desperately trying to make sense of things.

As detailed in the synopsis above, the story is set in a post-apocalyptic future and features a twelve-year-old male protagonist, named Riddley, on a quest to make sense of things.

Riddley speaks in broken English, and according to this quote provided within a Goodreads [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/134042120), he meets a pair of dogs, named Folleree & Folleroo, that stand up on their hind legs and talk like men.

> “7. Thay dogs stud up on thear hyn legs & taukin lyk men. Folleree sed, Lukin for the 1 you wil aul ways fyn thay 2. Folleroo sed, They 2 is twice as bad as the 1.”

Comment: Thank you, you are absolutely right.

Comment: @Julian Abernathy - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].